# How to resolve the error "Query failed: Unexpected error from server." in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, new-item

The Create New Item is the custom icon created in the list. After migration from SP 2010 to SP 2013, on clicking the Create New item icon the below error is displayed.

[image]

[image]

The message reads:

> "Query failed:
>   Unexpected error from server. The status code from response is '403'. The status text of response is 'FORBIDDEN'. null".

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: what happens if you manually navigate to newform.aspx? do you still get this error? that will help understand if its issue with icon click or actual page

Comment: Is there any custom code like JSOM trigger when clicking the icon ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is any custom script in your page which will cause this issue.

And For SharePoint 2013, you could try to use Rest API to create new list item:

```
    function SubmitListItem() {
        var title = $("#title").val();
        $.ajax
            ({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList4')/items",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify
                    ({
                        __metadata:
                        {
                            type: "SP.Data.MyList4ListItem"
                        },
                        Title: title
                    }),
                headers:
                {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
    }

</script>
    Title: <input type="text" id="title">
```